# simple race game with dynamic array in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, dynamic-arrays

I was doing homework for a C++ game that we have to do from CO SCI 136 class and the instructions states:

Modify your Homework 4 Problem 1 solution thus:

1. Replace the array with a dynamic array
2. Read the winning points M from a file
3. Read the number of players N from a file
4. Read the player names from a file.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I am having trobule with these errors:

```
Error   C2664   'void Player::setName(std::string &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::string' to 'std::string &'    player.cpp  7   
Error   C2511   'void Player::setName(const std::string &)': overloaded member function not found in 'Player'   player.cpp  18  
Error   C2597   illegal reference to non-static member 'Player::name'   player.cpp  19
```

Is there any way to fix these errors?

Here are my codes of

player.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Player
{
private:
    string name;
    int points;
    bool skipturn = false;

public:
    Player(const string& new_name = "No Name");
    string getName() const;
    int getPoints() const;
    void setName(string& new_name);
    void setPoints(int new_points);
    void setLossHalfPoints();
    void setSkipTurn(bool isSkip);
    bool isSkipTurn();
};
```

player.cpp

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "player.h"

Player::Player(const string& new_name)
{
    setName(new_name);
}
string Player::getName() const
{
    return name;
}
int Player::getPoints() const
{
    return points;
}
void Player::setName(const string& new_name)
{
    name = new_name;
}
void Player::setPoints(int new_points)
{
    points = new_points;
}

void Player::setLossHalfPoints()
{
    this->points /= 2;
}

void Player::setSkipTurn(bool isSkip)
{
    this->skipturn = isSkip;
}

bool Player::isSkipTurn()
{
    return this->skipturn;
}
```

source.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <random>
#include<fstream>
#include "player.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int M;
    int N;

    Player *player; //Declaring as a dynamic array
    player = new Player[N];
    string *names;
    names = new string[N];
    ifstream file, file1, file2; //opening the file in read mode
    string line;
    file.open("Mdata.dat");
    file >> M; //Reading the M data from the file
    file.close();
    file1.open("Ndata.dat");
    file1 >> N; //Reading the N data from the file
    file1.close();

    file2.open("names.dat");
    if (file2.is_open()) //if the file is open
    {
        while (!file2.eof()) //while the end of file is NOT reached
        {
            getline(file2, line); //get one line from the file
            for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
            {
                names[i] = line; //reading names from file into names array
            }
        }
        file2.close();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) //setting the player names from names array
    {
        player[i].setName(names[i]); player[i].setPoints(0);
    }

    default_random_engine dre(17890714);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> player_uid(0, N - 1);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dice_uid(1, 6);
    int index = player_uid(dre);
    do
    {
        index = (index + 1) % N;//implements circular array
        if (player[index].isSkipTurn())
        {
            cout << player[index].getName() << '/' << setw(2) << "skip turn" << endl;
            player[index].setSkipTurn(false);// clear skip turn
            index = (index + 1) % N;//implements circular array
        }
        int die1 = dice_uid(dre);
        int die2 = dice_uid(dre);
        int points = player[index].getPoints();
        player[index].setPoints(points + die1 + die2);
        if (player[index].getPoints() > M)
        {
            player[index].setLossHalfPoints();// set half of then points
            player[index].setSkipTurn(true);// set skip turn   
            cout << player[index].getName() << '/' << setw(2) << player[index].getPoints() << '/' << setw(2) << player[index].getPoints() * 2 << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << player[index].getName() << '/' << setw(2) << die1 + die2 << '/' << setw(2) << player[index].getPoints() << endl;
        }
    } while (player[index].getPoints() != M);
    cout << player[index].getName() << " wins" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude, but the compiler errors are telling you the *exact* problems.  what about them don't you understand?

Comment: Please give the filenames of the shown contents and indicate which lines are those mentioned by the error messages. Add a `// this line error 1/2/3` to do so.

Comment: You *declared* `void setName(string& new_name);` but *defined* `void Player::setName(const string& new_name)` - the `const` means they are different functions

Comment: An aside: `bool isSkipTurn()` should probably be `bool isSkipTurn() const`

Comment: Please don't use snippets. They're for HTML/CSS/JavaScript, not C++.

Comment: This is my first time using this site guys. How about show some respect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the compiler error.

```
Error C2664 'void Player::setName(std::string &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::string' to 'std::string &' player.cpp 7
```

It is complaining that it cannot convert `const std::string` to `std::string` when calling the `setName()` function at line 7 of player.cpp. But we have a `setName` function in the player class, right? What's wrong?

If you look at it more carefully in your Player.h, the declaration of the function `setName` is missing the `const` attribute.

```
void setName(string& new_name);
```

If you add `const` to this that will solve it.

Comment: Thank you I get it now. It fixes the errors, but it now has this: Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'N' is being used without being initialized. occurred

Comment: @Luis Look at your code. First you declare `N`, then you use `N` then you read `N`. That's the wrong order, it should be declare `N`, read `N`, use `N`. Now think about the error message again. Does it make sense now? You can't use a variable before you've given it a value.

Comment: @john I get it now. I just declare  int N = 0;

Comment: @Luis No, because that gives `N` a value so the error goes away, but you've given it the wrong value, the correct value is not zero its that value you read from the file. The order that things occur in your program is important, in particular you have to give variables the values that you want **before** you use those variables in other calculations, so `file1 >> N;` must be before `player = new Player[N];` and `names = new string[N];` not afterwards.

Comment: @Luis Your program is a sequence of instructions that are executed in the order they are given. What you have is like a recipe that says 1) Mix the sugar and the butter, 2) weigh out a 1/4 pound of sugar. The order is back to front.